# Facebook meta tags - Inferred Property warnings

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a page with facebook like button, its doc type and namespace looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" id="facebook" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

When i view page source meta tags looks like this (These have been commented to skip the w3 parser.)

```
     <!-- <meta property="og:title" content="Mysitename" />
     <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="abc" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://testing.site.com/abc/123/show" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://testing.site.com/images/logo.jpg" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="www.Myoriginalsite.com" />
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="10101010" /> -->
```

This is a ruby on rails project so, url and image were taken using erb, (Note - So the header of this page is coming from a different page and combining with body through rails),

```
 <meta property="og:url" content="<%= "http://" + request.env["HTTP_HOST"] + request.request_uri%>" />
   <meta property="og:image" content="<%= "http://" + request.env["HTTP_HOST"]%>/images/logo.jpg" />
```

Relating to fb_app_id 10101010, website url is defined as http://testing.site.com/ in the facebook  application.

When the debug the url testing.site.com/abc/123/show using developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/  it gives like button warnings and open graph warnings, as Inferred Property errors. And the canonical url is  esting.site.com/abc/123/show

Fb like button html is this.

```
 <div style="margin-top: 5px" class="fb-like" data-href="<%= "http://" + request.env["HTTP_HOST"] + request.request_uri %>" data-send="false" data-width="250" data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="dark" data-font="verdana"></div>
```

But I want display my meta tag properties when clicking like button. Like button is working properly. But it take those random values as meta tags. Can any of you help please???

Answer (score 0):

Your meta tags are commented out in the code you provided, you should remove HTML comments (`<!--` and `-->`) that wrap OpenGraph meta tags before Facebook Linter be able to crawl 'em.